# Parse SignUp Failure Adds User Regardless

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using the Java Parse framework and have a simple page which calls the method to signup the user with an email, username and password.

If all entered correctly the user signs up without issue. However, even if the user fails the sign up process, I can see in the Parse data browser at their website that a user is added anyway.

E.G I enter a username but no password or email address, the sign up will fail as expected, but a user object with that username will be added anyway.

This means when the user tries again, with the same username for example, it will say that username is taken, despite it being from a failed signup.

Any way arounds this?

Here is my code:

```
function signUpUser(email, username, password) 
{
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("email", email); //optional
    user.set("username", username); //required
    user.set("password", password); //required

    //Set other fields
    //

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            //Hooray! Let them use the app now
            alert("success, signed up!");
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to do some validation in your `signUpUser()` function, possibly even prompting the user to fill in the required field(s).

```
// use whatever lengths match your rules
if (username.length > 3 && password.length > 5) {
    // ... your existing user.signUp() code here ...
} else {
    // ... warn user about invalid username/password ...
}
```